# Cannot run openquery on linked server

Tags: sql, db2, etl, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I am running a query on linked server (IBM DB2) the reason I am doing this is because it takes lot of time to execute a simple query.
below are the two queries, the first one runs successfully so the issue is not with the query

```
 select top 10 * from [AS400TS_LNK].[TEST].[AUPRDDBF].CONTACCT where  actrno = '8971'  

  select * from openquery(AS400TS_LNK, 'select * from [TEST].[AUPRDDBF].CONTACCT where  actrno = ''8971''')
```

and the error I get while running the open query

> OLE DB provider "DB2OLEDB" for linked server "AS400TS_LNK" returned message "Token *N was not valid. Valid tokens: *N. SQLSTATE: 42601, SQLCODE: -104".
>
> Msg 7321, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>
> An error occurred while preparing the query "select * from [AS400TS_LNK].[TEST].[AUPRDDBF].CONTACCT where  actrno = '8971'" for execution against OLE DB provider "DB2OLEDB" for linked server "AS400TS_LNK".

Comment: Just a wild guess here, but easy to test. Try removing the square brackets from the `openquery` statement...

Comment: As @user1429080 mentioned, using square brackets to quote identifiers is a SQL Server thing; send standard SQL to the remote server, using double quotes for identifiers when necessary (which is not the case here anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * 
from openquery(AS400TS_LNK, 'select * from TEST.AUPRDDBF.CONTACCT where actrno = ''8971''')
```

Or, failing that, try this:

```
select * 
from openquery(AS400TS_LNK, 'select * from TEST.AUPRDDBF.CONTACCT') 
where actrno = '8971'
```